# PIE Only: SharedPreferences IllegalStateException

Tags: android

We're getting an IllegalStageException when trying to initialize our shared preferences singleton class but I don't know what's causing it.

Can anyone here advise me as to what may be causing this?

**NOTE**: This is ONLY happening on Pie

Here's the report from the Google Play Console (crash is not showing in Crashlytics):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:5876)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100 (ActivityThread.java:199)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1650)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6669)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:858)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences (ContextImpl.java:419)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences (ContextImpl.java:404)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences (ContextWrapper.java:174)
  at com.nbc.news.utils.SharedPreferences.<init> (SharedPreferences.java:27)
  at com.nbc.news.utils.SharedPreferences.init (SharedPreferences.java:44)
  at com.nbc.news.NbcNews.onCreate (NbcNews.java:122)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:5871)
```

Here's the init code:

```
private android.content.SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    private static SharedPreferences instance;

    private SharedPreferences(Context context) {
        Context appContext = context.getApplicationContext();

        sharedPreferences = appContext.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.database_name), Context.MODE_PRIVATE); // <- this is line #27
    }

    public android.content.SharedPreferences getPreference(){
        return sharedPreferences;
    }

    public static SharedPreferences getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("SharedPreferences must be initialized with context prior to use");
        }

        return instance;
    }

    public static void init(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new SharedPreferences(context); // <- this is line #44
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this

Comment: @hasan_shaikh unfortunately not.  we had to change the logic to only run once unlocked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I only found one or two puzzle pieces which may be helpful: the [source code of ContextImpl](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java) has two `IllegalStateException`s, one of them from a method `getSharedPreferences()` in line 426-454.

> "SharedPreferences in credential encrypted storage are not available until after user is unlocked"

This `IllegalStateException` is thrown from an `if` block which is executed only if the target SDK version is Oreo or higher

```
if (getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    if (isCredentialProtectedStorage()
         && 
        !getSystemService(UserManager.class).isUserUnlockingOrUnlocked(UserHandle.myUserId())) {

        throw new IllegalStateException("SharedPreferences in credential encrypted "
                                + "storage are not available until after user is unlocked");
     }
}
```

Searching the web for `isCredentialProtectedStorage()` led me to [FileBasedEncryption](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/file-based).

Since I don't know the details of your app's workflow I can only suggest to make sure that the app does not try to access a secured file while the device is locked.

Comment: Thanks for this, pointed me in just the right direction! I had a BroadcastReceiver set to listen for BOOT_COMPLETED & LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED events, and had followed the Lint prompt to include "directBootAware=true" back when Nougat came out. I would never have suspected a Preference-exception was actually caused by all that DirectBoot nonsense.

Comment: So, adding "directBootAware=true" in application tag solved this issue?

Comment: We too are facing the same issue for Android OS 8.0, 8.1 & 9.0. Seems like there is a restriction / protection in these OS versions. Any findings on this? How can we avoid this?

Comment: @venkat - if I understand MandisaW's comment correctly, using this attribute *caused* the Exception for their app

Comment: @Vrajesh Hirani - sorry, but I don't have any other information on this. But it looks like the new behavior is "as intended", so I guess we have to change the workflow of our apps to cope with it.

Comment: Ok @0X0nosugar. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @0X0nosugar The root cause for this in my app is GoogleAnalytics.getInstance() method which is part Google Services SDK.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem with Google Analytics. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: We are neither using  LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED nor android:directBootAware="true" but still getting this crash, any idea why?

Comment: @AsthaGarg - Hard to tell without any code. Best ask a new question containing a [MCVE]

Answer (score 7):

You must be trying to access `SharedPreferences` after `LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED` and before `BOOT_COMPLETED` which isn't allowed since Nougat / API 24 unless you migrate your preferences to the Device Protected Storage.

2 options here:

- Either remove the `LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED` action and the `android:directBootAware` flag from your Broadcast Receiver. This way your app will wait till `BOOT_COMPLETED` (when the user unlocks the device) before trying to access `SharedPreferences`.
- Or if you do need to access `SharedPreferences` after `LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED` and before `BOOT_COMPLETED`, make sure your migrate your preferences to the Device Protected Storage and use Device Protected Storage Context when calling `getSharedPreferences()`.

More details on the second option in the official docs: [Support Direct Boot mode](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/direct-boot)

Comment: Worked, thank you.

Comment: We are using only BOOT_COMPLETED not LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED but still getting this crash, any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to move the App Center initialization from Application class into MainActivity. This will helps you. We have to call the Sharepreference only after the app is ready(BootCompleted).