# java.lang.IllegalStateException android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences

Tags: android, kotlin, exception, google-play-console, illegalstateexception

I am getting this error on the play console and don't know where the issue exists and is this possible to solve the issue

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences

    java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
      at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences (ContextImpl.java:530)
      at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences (ContextImpl.java:506)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaek.zza
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaeo.zza
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaep.zza
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaes.zza
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaeq.zza
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzaps.run
      at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:923)
```

I am using on boot completed receiver to start my service if the device restarted successfully but this exception occurs.

Here is my receiver register in the manifest

```
<receiver
        android:name=".receiver.AutoStart"
        android:directBootAware="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: see this answer, maybe your problem solved https://stackoverflow.com/a/53837940/17781856

Comment: already go through this post